# Adding a button to last row of TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have added buttons to the `TableLayout` programmatically usin `TableRow`. Each row should include three buttons. If number of buttons is multiple of three there is no problem. All buttons are placed with same size. However the number of buttons for last row is less than three, its size is not matched with other buttons.

Here is my code:

```
tableView.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams
                .MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

 scrollView.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ScrollView.LayoutParams
                .MATCH_PARENT, ScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));

TableLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =  new TableLayout.LayoutParams
(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0,20,0,20);
int numberOfButtonsForLastRow = masalar.size() - numberOfRows*3;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) 
{
     tr = new TableRow(fragmentView.getContext());
     tr.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
     for (int j= 0;j<3;j++)
     {
         btn = new Button(getActivity());
         btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstyle);
         btn.setText(masalar.get(masaCounter));
         TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams
         .MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
         params.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);
         btn.setLayoutParams(params);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             }
          });
        tr.addView(btn);
        masaCounter++;
    }
    tableView.addView(tr);
}
if(numberOfButtonsForLastRow>0)
{
    tr = new TableRow(fragmentView.getContext());
    tr.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    for (int j= 0;j<numberOfButtonsForLastRow;j++)
    {
       btn = new Button(getActivity());
       btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstyle);
       btn.setText(masalar.get(masaCounter));
       TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams
        .MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       params.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);
       btn.setLayoutParams(params);
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

              }
         });
       tr.addView(btn);
       masaCounter++;
     }
     tableView.addView(tr);
 }
```

[image]

This is how the last button looks like. I want it to be same size with others. How can I do this?

Comment: where did you add the last one?

Comment: Inside the `if` statement. `if(numberOfButtonsForLastRow>0)`

Answer (score 0):

Add a Layout weight in your `TableRow.LayoutParams` same as what you did for the first 2 rows so buttons are divided into your `TableView`.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(btn.getWidth(), btn.getHeight());
```

Comment: When I do this the last button fills the whole row. I mean the width of last button is three times of other buttons.

Comment: @Blast try to Wrap the width

Comment: @Blast try instead of params just copy the width and hieght of the already added button. eddited

Comment: I have already tried it. The btn.getWidth() and btn.getHeight() returns 0. I have tried to get width and height before creating the new button.

Comment: @Blast i think the only way is to create a 2 dummy view with no background. Add the button then the two dummy view to the table row

Comment: I have set a width and height to all buttons. It works for my device but for all devices I should apply your suggestion. Thank you for your attetion.

Answer (score 0):

You need weigths, you devide the space of one row between (0 .. 1)

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams rows = new     
    TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 
    1.0f / (float) NUMBUTTONS);

row.setLayoutParams(rows););
```